# Programmatically Scrollable TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I place 60 buttons in my `TableLayout` and these buttons exceeds the screen so I need a scroll to show remaining buttons. I have tried this code but application is not working.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      TableLayout tableLayout;
      tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
      TableRow tr;
      int buttonNumber = 0;
      for (int i =0;i<30;i++)
      {
         tr = new TableRow(this);
         for (int j =0;j<2;j++)
         {
            buttonNumber++;
            final Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText("Button" + (buttonNumber));
            btn.setTag(buttonNumber);
            btn.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1));
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
                tr.addView(btn);

         }
                tableLayout.addView(tr);
     }
            ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
            sv.addView(tableLayout);
            super.setContentView(sv);
}
```

How can I create a scrollable `TableLayout` programmatically?

Comment: could you add also the xml code of R.layout.activity_main? so that i can see if there are bugs in there too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several solution, the main problem is that you are calling `setContentView()` multiple times and once also with `super.`

the best way to do it is to **remove** the ScrollView code:

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
sv.addView(tableLayout);
super.setContentView(sv);
```

and add it directly in the layout file `R.layout.activity_main`, that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
   int buttonNumber = 0;
        for (int i =0;i<30;i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j =0;j<2;j++)
            {
                buttonNumber++;
                final Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setText("Button" + (buttonNumber));
                btn.setTag(buttonNumber);
                btn.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1f));
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf((Integer)view.getTag()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                tr.addView(btn);

            }
            tableLayout.addView(tr);
        }
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        sv.addView(tableLayout);
        setContentView(sv);
}

![enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qLk1.png
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working. :/
I have a `LinearLayout` at the top of layout hierarchy. Should I remove it or change it with another layout type to make this code work?

Comment: don't forget to remove this line "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);"

Comment: just try to replace your onCreate() with my code and see what happen ?

Comment: I have removed `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` also tried to copy your code still not working. :/